# Node.js streams Object mode reference or copy

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pass-by-reference

Do node.js streams pass objects by reference in [ObjectMode](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode)? Unfortunately I can't find any documentation about that.

Comment: By simply testing it it seems to be by **reference** but still want to go sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into node.js source e.g. [stream.Readable](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js) shows that the object isn't copied. So it is passed by reference because this is javascripts method to pass objects.